# MS Access: Allowing numbers and Backspace only

Tags: vba, ms-access

How can I only allow the user only to type numbers and backspace in a field?

```
Private Sub Field_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)

    If Not IsNumeric(Chr(KeyAscii)) Then KeyAscii = 0

End Sub
```

With this the user also can't use Backspace...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
If Not IsNumeric(Chr(KeyAscii)) And KeyAscii <> 8 Then KeyAscii = 0
```

Comment: Thx, that's what I was searching for ;)

Answer (score 1):

What about <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>Arrow</kbd>  keys etc. ?

I'd rather use a validation rule for "numbers only".

http://allenbrowne.com/ValidationRule.html

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways

---

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 56, 57

        Case Else
        KeyAscii = 0
    End Select

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

    If KeyAscii < 48 Or KeyAscii > 57 Then KeyAscii = 0

End Sub
```